# JSOM Get List Item Property Bag

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, rest, jsom, sppropertybag

How to access List Item's Property Bag?

I am trying to replace all properties from one item to another.

```
var oldItems = oldList.getItems(query);
var newItems = newList.getItems(query);
context.load(oldItems);
context.load(newItems);

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.successGetListItemId), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

...

```
oldDoc = oldItems.getById(10);
newDoc = newItems.getById(4);
context.load(oldDoc);
context.load(newDoc);

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.successGetListItemId), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

...

```
var mi = newDoc.get_item('MetaInfo');
oldDoc.set_item('MetaInfo', mi);
oldDoc.update();

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.successGetListItemId), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

Answer (score 0):

This clones an Item (By id) to a new Item in the same List:
So needs some refactoring to set the `get_fields()` in an existing Item in the `getEnumerator` loop

*sorry for the short notations, this came from code stuck into a Calculated Column Formula, so had to be minified (because every item added the same code to the page)*

```
function cloneItem(id) {
    var c = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
        l = c.get_web().get_lists().getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()),
        i = l.getItemById(id),
        f = l.get_fields(),
        n, e, d, m, v,
        url = _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath;
    c.load(i);
    c.load(f);
    c.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            n = l.addItem(new SP.ListItemCreationInformation());
            e = f.getEnumerator();
            while (e.moveNext()) {
                d = e.get_current();
                m = d.get_internalName();
                if (!(d.get_readOnlyField() 
                       || d.get_hidden() 
                       || ['Attachments', 'ContentType'].indexOf(m) > -1)
                   ) {
                    v = i.get_item(m);
                    if (v) n.set_item(m, v);
                }
            }
            n.update();
            c.load(n);
            c.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                document.location = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/')) 
                                     + '/EditForm.aspx?ID=' + n.get_id();
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: Read question before answering :-)

Comment: Okay, sorry. I misunderstood then. Thought you wanted to use JSOM to copy properties from one item to another.

Answer (score 0):

You should just replace following string of the code

```
var mi = newDoc.get_item('MetaInfo');
```

with this

```
var mi = newDoc.get_fieldValues().MetaInfo;
```

And your solution will be work.